# std::min_element returning unexpected result from class objects

Tags: c++

I use std::min_element on this Node object I created that has an index. I have a std::set container that holds 10 Nodes with different indices, and then I call std::min_element to get the Node with the lowest index number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    Node(int index) : _index(index) {}

    int index() const { return _index; }

    inline bool operator< (const Node &right) { return this->index() < right.index(); }

private:
    int _index;
};

int main()
{
    set<Node*> s;

    for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) //10 , 9 , 8 ...
        s.insert(new Node(i));

    Node *lowest = *min_element(s.begin(), s.end());
    cout << lowest->index() << endl;

    //free
    for(set<Node*>::iterator iter = s.begin(); iter != s.end(); iter++)
        delete *iter;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `10` but sure be `1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The key is that `s` does not contain`Nodes`. It contains pointers. That determines ordering and equivalence.

Comment: Not your issue, but use `inline bool operator< (const Node &right) const {...}` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `set<Node*>`, not a `set<Node>`. So it's using the standard pointer `operator<`, not the one that you defined. If you change your type to be `set<Node>` and add your `Node`s in by value, everything will work just fine.

Also note that `set<T>` is already sorted by `operator<`, so if you had:

```
std::set<Node> nodes;
// add nodes here
Node& lowest = *nodes.begin();
```

You don't have to use `min_element`. That algorithm would be more useful if you were searching in a `vector`:

```
std::vector<Node*> nodes;
// add nodes here
auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(nodes), std::end(nodes),
    [](Node* a, Node* b){ return *a < *b; }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! But just for learning purposes, say this was an std::vector, and I must use pointers to objects, what would be the solution to that?

Comment: @Pilpel Updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: Never seen that `[] (...) {...}` syntax before. What does it do? Does it create a function inside min_element()?